# Fixing previous/next pagination links for AJAX requested django-tables2 table

Tags: django, django-tables2

I'm using `django-tables2` to generate my tables. For regular GET requests, I return the table in the context and `{% render_table mytable %}` in the template, all works well. However, sometimes I make a request via `AJAX`, and in the view just return `mytable.as_html()` in the context. This works largely OK too, but the pagination ('Previous/Next') links do not point to the correct URLS (e.g. they might just point to `?page=2` and not `page=?&myvariable1=blue&myvariable2=red` for example).

It appears that it is the `render_table` templatetag that is responsible for making these `previous/next` links point to the right places based on the `request.GET`. Is it possible to just `from django_tables2.templatetags.django_tables2 import render_table` and somehow feed the `render_table` function mytable and the request data to create a table with the right paging links?

I know I could probably do this with jQuery, but I wanted to see if there was a Django solution first.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case it helps someone else:

Instead of passing the table back to the AJAX call with `table.as_html()`, I ended up doing

```
table_str = render_to_string('django_tables2/table.html',
                             RequestContext(request,
                                            {'table': tableContext['table']}) )
```

This gives me the table html as a string, but the difference is now the `Previous/Next` and sorting links have the correct links from the request string added. When the django-tables2 table leaves the view it does not have the correct links, they get added in the template when `{% render_table mytable %}` tag is called, this in turn uses the `django_tables2/table.html` by default, within which the `querystring` tag does the actual work of rendering the URLs for the `Previous/Next` from the request etc..